# How to change the order of x variables with bound data

Tags: r, ggplot2, rbind

I'd like to change the order of the x-variables in the graph below while keeping before and after side by side. In other words, I'd like to arrange the data set from the smallest mean change to the biggest mean change. I've found some code but it's really meant for ordering x-variables in a single data frame. However, I bound my data to show before and after effects on the mean. This of course plots it in the default alphabetical order. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code and the data frame thus far:

### Data Frame 1

```
solm <-  data.frame(mean = 
                      c(1160,690,380,365,375,475, 725, 675,2685,675,415,905,
                        1135,3350,400,1460,385, 675, 415,2875), 
                    std.dev = c(760,310,0,15,50,125, 125, 300,765,300,35,555,
                                785,0,50,0,15, 325, 65,425),
                    class = c("previous"),
                    group = c("D.marsupialis","D.novemcinctus",
                              "P.maximus","T.tetrodactyla",
                              "C.albifrons","S.ignitus", "S.igniventris","C. paca",
                              "C. taczanowskii","D.punctata",
                              "A.microtis","P.flavus","E.barbara",
                              "M.frenata","L.pardalis","L.tigrinus",
                              "L.weidii","P.onca", "M.americana",
                              "M.chunyi"))
solm

##Data frame 2

obsm <- data.frame(mean = 
                     c(1290,825,460,930,920,1165,1050,1050,2740,1275,565,1226,
                       1900.5,2742.5,550,2363.5,445, 1050, 550,2750), 
                   std.dev = c(890,445,80,580,570,815, 450, 700,820,925,185,876,
                               1550.5,814.5,200,1097.5,75, 700, 200,550),
                   class = c("observed"),
                   group = c("D.marsupialis","D.novemcinctus",
                             "P.maximus","T.tetrodactyla",
                             "C.albifrons","S.ignitus", "S.igniventris", "C. paca",
                             "C. taczanowskii","D.punctata",
                             "A.microtis","P.flavus","E.barbara",
                             "M.frenata","L.pardalis","L.tigrinus",
                             "L.weidii","P.onca", "M.americana",
                             "M.chunyi"))
```

### Combo

```
d <- rbind(solm, obsm)
d
```

### Plot

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=group, y=mean, col=class)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = mean+std.dev, ymax = mean-std.dev), 
                  position = position_dodge(0.5))+theme_bw()+ 
  labs(x="Mammal Species", y="Elevation (m)")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())+
  theme (axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, 
                                    face="bold.italic"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(300, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 
                              3000, 3500, 4000))
```